# while loops not working for def() functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying a program that adds two elements together to make a new one, and you have to make as many elements as you can in this process e.g. https://littlealchemy.com/
But I can't seem to get my definitions to re-run inside of a while loop.
When I run it, it doesn't seem to strip the `[]` out of the list. What's more, it only runs once and then leaves the terminal blank.

Sorry about the abbreviations, I prefer it like that, but I can change it if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou.

Here is my code:

```
element1 = ""
element2 = ""
de = [] #discovered elements
ne = "" #new element
o1 = ""
o2 = ""
pne = ""

print("You have unlocked Fire, Water, Earth, and Air")
print("To see your unlocked elements, enter in 'menu' into the 'give the first element' option")

e1 = input("Give the first element ") #element 1
e2 = input("Give the second element ") #element 2

def pnestuff():
    pne = str(de); pne.strip("["); pne.strip("]")

def operate(x, y, z):
    global e1
    global e2
    o1 = (x)
    o2 = (y)
    ne = (z)
    if (e1 == o1 and e2 == o2) or (e1 == o2 and e2 == o1):
        de.append(ne)
        print("You have unlocked "+ne+"!")
        print("Your complete element list:")
        pnestuff()
        print(pne)
        e1 = ""
        e2 = ""

def menu():
    global e1
    global e2
    if e1 == "menu":
        print("You have unlocked:")
        pnestuff()
        print(pne)
        e1 = ""
        e2 = ""

#===============================================================================#

while 1:

    menu()

    operate("fire", "water", "steam")
```

Comment: In general, your whole code fragment makes little sense. But this particular statement: `pne.strip("[")` (and the following one) are not doing what you think they are doing. Read `help(str.strip)` before using this function.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, your code is a disater.  But let's focus on your immediate problem.  I would guess it's this:

```
def pnestuff():
    pne = str(de); pne.strip("["); pne.strip("]")
```

which wants to set the global `pne` but fails to declare it global, and fails to understand that strings are *immutable*:

```
def pnestuff():
    global pne
    pne = str(de).lstrip("[").rstrip("]")
```

though a better definition might be:

```
def pnestuff():
    global pne
    pne = ', '.join(de)
```

Comment: Or even better `def pnestuff(pne, de):` to pass in the variables you want to use instead of have the function operate on globals.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the two insert elements lines inside the while loop. *facepalm*. and thankyou everyone for the help with x.join